# How to increase dialogflow microphone audio input?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am using Google Dialogflow ES to implement in my PHP project. Right now dialogflow accepts audio input around 8-10 seconds. I want to increase this limit, i.e. dialogflow should accept audio input of minimum 30 seconds. How to configure this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Dialogflow accepts audio input"? Are you building for a specific voice integration?

Comment: @Jordi Yes I am working on it which accepts audio microphone inputs as well

Comment: For which integration are you developing specifically?